# jquery SAVE dialog on clicking link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a SAVE file dialog show when i chick a link on my page. At the least i want to initiate a download of the file whos link was clicked. Here is what i have tried.

Just for kicks i put the "alert" statement to ensure the code was being rendred, and it is. Firebug does not catch any errors.

```
//download button navigate
var downloadButton = $('#downloadLinkLabel', window.parent.document);
var downloadButtonFunc = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
    alert('its working');
    window.location.href = 'image.jpg';
};
addEventHandler(downloadButton[0], 'click', downloadButtonFunc);
```

Here is the HTML code

```
<div id="s-Label_61" class="label firer ie-background commentable">
    <div class="valign"><span>Download</span></div>
</div>
```

I am using a prototyping tool to create a UI and have a underlying browser page which is running all my custom scripts. The prototyping tool only allows for simple urls and does not allow for setting headers/attributes. If there is a way to inject this code via jquery then that would work

Comment: You should use a static link to a page that sends the proper attachment headers instead, then the image will be downloaded automatically when clicking the link without any javascript.

Comment: You can make a "save" dialog of sorts, but you can't override the  browser dialog if that's what you were planning.

Comment: yes that would be the most sensible thing to do but i cannot do so in my scenario. I am using a prototyping tool to create a UI and have a underlying browser page which is running all my custom scripts. The prototyping tool only allows for simple urls and does not allow for setting headers.

Comment: @zarazthuztra i do not want to override the browser dialog. On the contrary i actually want the browser dialog to show up.

Comment: @codeNinja Cool. I've seen people wanting to do that before >.> 
In any case, why not make some sort of AJAX request to a server side script that sets the headers and sends the image as the response?

Comment: an ajax request won't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the HTML5 download attribute for supporting browsers, for non-supporting browsers I believe the only solution would be setting the appropriate headers.

```
<a href="http://img.com/img.png" download="myImage.png">DOWNLOAD THIS IMAGE</a>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CsFDD/)

**EDIT:**

You can (almost) just as easily create the link and click it with javascript

```
$('#s-Label_61 span').on('click', function() {
     var a = document.createElement('a');
     a.download = 'myImage.png';
     a.href = '/link/to/image.png';
     a.click();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CsFDD/2/)

Comment: per my comment above. i cannot do so in my scenario. I am using a prototyping tool to create a UI and have a underlying browser page which is running all my custom scripts. The prototyping tool only allows for simple urls and does not allow for setting headers/attributes. If there is a way to inject this code via jquery then that would work

Comment: @codeNinja - of course you can, you can create an anchor with the proper href and the download property, and just click it with javascript, see edited answer.

Comment: Your answer was excellent and the only way to force any thing to be downloaded. thanks.

Comment: Please post a old browser support as well. This is only modern browser fix. Thank you,

Comment: @SanjokGurung - there is no cross-browser clientside fix, if you have to support older browsers this has to be done on the serverside by sending the proper content-disposition headers.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use html 5, you can have the image on Base64 and href the url:

"image/octet-stream,Base64"